# Pass application context to celery in flask framework

Tags: python, flask, celery, factory-pattern

I tried to add celery to my existing flask project. After adding, I got an "working outside of application context" error while running. It seems that the celery worker lacks of my application context. But I am not sure where to pass the applicaiton context to celery worker in this case.

Here is my current structure (I tried to follow a factory pattern with blueprints and api documentions):

```
-run.py
-app
    -module1
      -controller.py
      -model.py
      -service.py
    -__init__.py
    -config.py
```

---

For the init.py

```
# __init__.py
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_cors import CORS
from app.config import Config
from flask_restplus import Api
from celery import Celery

cors = CORS()
db = SQLAlchemy()
api = Api()
celery = Celery(__name__, broker=Config.CELERY_BROKER_URL, include=["app.module1.service"])

def create_app(config_class = Config):
    app = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='')
    app.config.from_object(Config)

    cors.init_app(app)
    db.init_app(app)
    api.init_app(app=app)
    celery.conf.update(app.config)

    from app.module1.controller import blueprint
    from app.module1.controller import ns

    app.register_blueprint(blueprint)
    api.add_namespace(ns)

    return app
```

For the run.py

```
from app import create_app
app = create_app()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(threaded=True, debug=True)
```

For the service.py

```
from app import db, celery
@celery.task(bind=True)
def service1(self):
    # do somethigng & return
```

For the controller.py

```
from flask import Blueprint
from flask_restplus import Api, Resouce
blueprint = Blueprint('service', __name__)
apis = Api(app = blueprint)
ns = apis.namespace('service', 'service description')
@ns.route("/")
class SomeList(Resource):
    def get(self):
        service1.apply_async()
        # return
```

Comment: Check out the docmentation for this usage: http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/1.0/patterns/celery/

Comment: @Grey Li, Thanks, I restructured and tried this. but after I called the task, I got an error with: sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: When initializing mapper mapped class Experiment->experiment, expression 'GenerationRule.experiment_id' failed to locate a name ("name 'GenerationRule' is not defined"). If this is a class name, consider adding this relationship() to the <class 'balancer.experiment.model.Experiment'> class after both dependent classes have been defined. But if I am not running with celery, it works fine.

Comment: Well, it's a new problem, maybe it's better to create a new post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the confusion is based on the fact that you are trying to "pass" an application context to the Celery worker. In reality the Flask process cannot pass a context to the worker because they are different processes. The Celery worker process needs to create its own Flask application instance by calling `create_app()` so that it can push its own app contexts when needed.

So for example, in your `service1` task:

```py
from app import db, celery, create_app

@celery.task(bind=True)
def service1(self):
    app = create_app()
    with app.app_context():
        # do somethigng & return
```

To make this a bit more efficient, you can create a single global `app` that is shared by all your tasks:

```py
from app import db, celery, create_app
app = create_app()

@celery.task(bind=True)
def service1(self):
    with app.app_context():
        # do somethigng & return
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this~

Comment: @Miguel wouldn't this cause cyclical imports ig the service1 is in a blueprint?

Comment: I put app = create_app() inside service1(), to avoid conflicts between my existing global variable "app" and this one. I also found shared_task which seemed to offer an alternative, but didn't work.